# How to get X and Y from 1 point?

Tags: string, coordinates

I am doing this in java, but the answer isn't java specific.

Here is my code:

```
    String map = "                                                   x    " +
                 "     x o                          xxxx   xxxx   xxxx    " +
                 "     x                       xxxx                       " +
                 "     xxxx               xxxx                            " +
                 "         xx      xxxxxx                                 " +
                 "           xx                                           " +
                 "             xx                                         " +
                 "               xx                                  x    " +
                 "                 xx                                x    " +
                 "                   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    ";

    for(int i = 0; i < map.length(); i++) {
        if(map.charAt(i) == 'x') {
            platform[i] = CCSprite.sprite("platform_2.gif");
            platform[i].setPosition(x, y); //How to get x and y?
            addChild(platform[i]);
            platformCount++;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, for every "x" in the map string, I want to create a new platform. Now, each line of the string is 57 characters long, and I need to get the X and Y value of where that X is, but all I can retrieve is the charAt the "i" variable, in the for statement. What is a logical way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = i % width;
int y = i / width;
```

…where `%` is [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) and `/` is [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division).

Comment: To add some verbage - `%` is modulo and `/` must be truncating division.

Comment: @icktoofay for some reason it doesnt work; all the platforms get jumbled in the top left corner

Comment: @Qasim: Perhaps multiply the X and Y coordinates by the size of the sprite.

Comment: @icktoofay I feel stupid now. I had that before, but once I began using the string method, I forgot to add it in. Thanks.